# How to load JS module into LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'd like to loadScript(MyLib) with type=modules to getting import instead sharing via window. is it possible to do that?
`loadScript(MyLib)` is loaded as native `type=text/application`. but i'd like to inject as `<script type=modules />`

```
import CalendarBuild from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/CalendarBuild';


    connectedCallback() {

        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, CalendarBuild),
        ])
        .then(() => {
            const calendarEl = this.template.querySelector('div.calendar-root');
            CalendarBuild.renderCalendar(calendarEl, {
                events: [],
                unFilterEvents: [],
                locationId: "locationId",
                isFetching: false,
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                handleChangeLocation: () => {},
                handleChangeLocationSetting: () => {},
                refetchLessonsOnCalendar: () => {},
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('---error when init---', error?.message);
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

The original solution you're asking for simply isn't possible. Locker Service (LS) and Lightning Web Security (LWS) are both designed to block `script` tags from loading or executing by all the usual means you'd do so on the open web. This is a security feature designed to prevent rogue scripts from going outside the security sandbox.

That said, if you want to use the code as a module, just do so as a service component. To do this, create a new component bundle, e.g. `calendarBuild`, and within it, populate `calendarBuild.js` with the entire source code from the library you want to include, including any `export` statements.

At this point, you should be able to import it as a regular module:

```
import CalendarBuild from 'c/calendarBuild';
```

Note that in order for this to work, you'll still need to define the component selected by `this.template.querySelector('div.calendar-root');` with the `lwc:dom="manual"` attribute:

```
<div lwc:dom="manual"></div>
```

This element must not contain any content, as shown above.

Comment: Do you have any sample code for this, I'm not familiar so not really got this solution

Comment: @vctqs1 See [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/js-share-code.html) for more information. The code in my answer is the sample code. It's literally just creating a new component, putting the JS inside the component's JS, and then importing it. You can then call the method in the `renderedCallback` life cycle handler.